# Pressing tab doesn't cycle through my form inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, mdbootstrap

I'm using ReactJs 18 and MDBootstrap for styling.

I have a form component that I use inside a modal (I have many forms but trying to use the same modal). Pressing tab or shift-tab to go forwards or backwards through the inputs of my form should work.

Pressing tab or shift-tab does nothing and I stay in the same input, the form is functional on its own when I put it outside the modal and everything works fine, and adding tabindex does not do anything.

Here is a link to a project I created on code sandbox that recreates the issue .
[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-feistel-fpyz96)

Please click on the Card component at the top of the first form to pop up the modal form.